# Selecting rows according to similarity using MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table and values

```
name    dob         doj         sex     salary
dev     1989-01-01  2012-01-01  m       1200
anish   1989-07-14  1995-01-01  m       5000
aasha   1988-12-15  2009-06-05  f       5000
```

I need to following output.

```
name    dob         doj         sex     salary
anish   1989-07-14  1995-01-01  m       5000
aasha   1988-12-15  2009-06-05  f       5000
```

I need to **select** details of those who earn the **same amount**

Comment: what do you mean by rest ignored, please explain more

Comment: I need to display details of those employees who earn the same amount. In the above case **5000** in rows three and four.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with 2 queries. Inner query selects all salaries that 2 or more people have.

```
SELECT
  name,
  dob,
  doj,
  sex,
  t.salary
FROM
  table AS t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                salary
              FROM
                table
              GROUP BY
                salary
              HAVING
                COUNT(*) > 1) AS s 
     USING (salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict rows to users such that another user exists who earns the same amount, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM person p2
    WHERE p1.salary=p2.salary -- Has the same salary
      AND (p1.name <> p2.name -- But is not the same person
        OR p1.dob <> p2.dob
        OR p1.doj <> p2.doj
        OR p1.sex <> p2.sex
      )
)
```

Adding a primary key would simplify the query, because a `p1.pk <> p2.pk` check would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. This is kind of an assignment, they provided the table so I can't add primary key

Comment: yes the query worked just fine. Got the expected output